# Bash: How to minus from the value every time and not let it reset back to its original value?

Tags: bash

This is just a simple script and I may be a dumb or blind but.. I don't understand how to make it so that it doesn't return back to value 100.. I want to minus from 100 until it is 0 so that if health = 0 --> quit
This is just a simple program test. I need to correct this one before moving on with my idea.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
health=100

(( punch = RANDOM % 11 ))
(( new_health = $health - $punch ))
echo "You did $punch damage to yourself. Your health is now: $new_health%"
if [[ $new_health -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "You lost!"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: You'd need to create a loop inside the script to keep the script going otherwise it wont work because your script terminates after 1 punch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a loop, punching yourself every 1 sec :

```
#!/bin/bash
health=100
while true
do
    (( punch = RANDOM % 11 ))
    (( health = $health - $punch ))
    echo "You did $punch damage to yourself. Your health is now: $health%"
    if [[ $health -le 0 ]]; then
        echo "You lost!"
        exit
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Or you could build the condition into the loop construct: `while (( health > 0 )); do (( health -= RANDOM % 11 )); echo "..."; done; echo "you lost"`

Comment: @Benjamin sure, I just wanted to post a solution with the minimal changes to OP's code